# MVC and SignalR - avoid duplicating template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, signalr

I am using MVC to display a table of data using Razor and html in my View.
To make it more "real time" I added a SignalR Hub that refreshes the table with new rows and deletes the old ones. (not all rows are changed)

Problems is: now I've got a duplicate of row template. both in Html-Razor and in JavaScript, I also had to hook on button handlers and other logic twice.

Is there any better design for this?

Comment: Any sample code to exemplify the description in your question and the specific problem encountered?

Comment: Take a look at knockout.js: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html

Comment: Move it all to knockout and skip razor

Answer (score 0):

Skip knockout and send HTML through signalr.

You can easily in code call a partial razor view and get the html result, then send the html result through signalr. Search stackoverflow for (rendering razor view to string).

This way no duplicate code, as the same razor child view is reused.

Don't forget to rebind the javascript handlers, or use "on" on a fixed parent container.